# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: upload

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to upload an image to an sqlite3 database but i keep receiving this error

it has created a file with the right name i want for the database but it is empty.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 748, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: upload
```

and this

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: upload
[SQL: INSERT INTO upload (filename, data) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('White Brown Elegant Happy Easter Instagram Story (1).png', <memory at 0x7f860abf5fc0>)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

this is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

#create the app
app = Flask(__name__)

#configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///ocr.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

#create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Upload(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(50))
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['image']
        upload = Upload(filename=file.filename, data=file.read())
        db.session.add(upload)
        db.session.commit()
        db.create_all()
        
        return f'Uploaded: {file.filename}'
    
    return render_template('index.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

Comment: @python_user. Thank you so much!!! I just needed to write the create_all() function call under the app.app_context line.